# Set radio button value checked from different radio button selection

Tags: android

I want to get radio button checked value from 1st activity to 2nd activity. 2nd activity contains layout of list view. the xml file of list view has a radio group. I want to set that radio button value from 1st activity to this file.

[[image: 1st activity image]]

[[image: 1st activity radio button]

[[image: 2nd activity radio list view]

AttendanceActivity.java

```
    ListView attendanceListView;
    String[] penNumber;
    Button saveAttendance;
    RadioButton presentRadio,absentRadio;
    RadioGroup attendanceRadio;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);

    View inflatedView = 
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.attendance_list_item, null);
    presentRadio = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.present_radio);
    absentRadio = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.absent_radio);
    attendanceRadio = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.AttendanceRadio);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int aorp = intent.getIntExtra("aorb", 1);
    if(aorp ==1)
    {
        attendanceRadio.check(R.id.present_radio);
    }
    else if(aorp ==2)
    {
        attendanceRadio.check(R.id.absent_radio);
    }
    penNumber = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.penNo);

    attendanceListView = findViewById(R.id.attendanceListView);
    saveAttendance = findViewById(R.id.saveAttendance);

    AttendanceListViewAdapter customAdapter = new 
    AttendanceListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), penNumber);
    attendanceListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    saveAttendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(AttendanceActivity.this, 
    AttendanceSummaryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
   }
```

faculty_home_page.kt

```
     alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(alertRadioStatus, -1, 
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialogInterface, i ->

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "Mostly Students are " + alertRadioStatus[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            when (i) {
                0 ->
                    aorp=1
                1 ->
                    aorp=2
            }
            val attendancePage = Intent(this@Faculty_Home_Page, AttendanceActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(attendancePage)
            attendancePage.putExtra("a_p_radio", aorp)
            dialogInterface.dismiss()

        })
        alertDialog.show()
        }
```

AttendanceListItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:padding="10dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pen_number_list"
    app:layout_widthPercent="44%"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:text="@string/Pen_View"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/AttendanceRadio"
    app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_marginEndPercent="1%"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/present_radio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/forest_green"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_marginStartPercent="1%"
        app:layout_marginEndPercent="1%" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/absent_radio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:buttonTint="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/leave_radio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:buttonTint="@color/yellow_full"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/late_radio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/orange_full"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</RadioGroup>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: USe sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). When the value of the first radio button changes, you can save the value in SharedPreferences. Then, when you open your second activity (or a dialog) you can check the value saved in the previous activity and set the radio buttons according to that value.